# Monaco client won't connect to Eclipse JDT server

Tags: java, backend, eclipse-jdt, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I want to add Java Intellisense to my Monaco client. For this I will connect the Eclipse JDT server with the Monaco client.

Monaco client link: https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient
Eclipse JDT server: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls.git

I was able to build and run both the JDT server and the Monaco client as per their documentation.

I am running the Monaco express server, which is present in the `example` folder of the Monaco repo.

I made the following changes in the Monaco repo before running: `yarn run start`

1. Made a folder Demo and added Java folder to it, where I added
   `file.java`. (Demo -> Java -> File.java)
2. Made changes in `client.ts` file and this is how it looks:

   ```
    // register Monaco languages
   monaco.languages.register({
   id: 'java',
   extensions: ['.java'],
   aliases: [java],
   mimetypes: ['application/text']
     })


   monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
       model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'java', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///home/imocha/python-lang-cli/monaco-languageclient/example/src/java/file.java')),
       glyphMargin: true,
       lightbulb: {
           enabled: true
       }
   });

   // register Monaco languages
   monaco.languages.register({
       id: 'java',
       extensions: ['.java'],
       aliases: [java],
       mimetypes: ['application/text']
     })


   monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
       model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'java', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///home/imocha/python-lang-cli/monaco-languageclient/example/src/java/file.java')),
       glyphMargin: true,
       lightbulb: {
           enabled: true
       }
   });


   // register Monaco languages
   monaco.languages.register({
       id: 'java',
       extensions: ['.java'],
       aliases: [java],
       mimetypes: ['application/text']
     })


   monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
       model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'java', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///home/imocha/python-lang-cli/monaco-languageclient/example/src/java/file.java')),
       glyphMargin: true,
       lightbulb: {
           enabled: true
       }
   });


   // register Monaco languages
   monaco.languages.register({
       id: 'java',
       extensions: ['.java'],
       aliases: [java],
       mimetypes: ['application/text']
     })


   monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
       model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'java', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///home/imocha/python-lang-cli/monaco-languageclient/example/src/java/file.java')),
       glyphMargin: true,
       lightbulb: {
           enabled: true
       }
   });
   ```
3. My `server.ts` file is as folow:

   ```
   import * as ws from "ws";
   import * as http from "http";
   import * as url from "url";
   import * as net from "net";
   import * as express from "express";
   import * as rpc from "@codingame/monaco-jsonrpc";
   import { launch } from "./json-server-launcher";


   process.on('uncaughtException', function (err: any) {
       console.error('Uncaught Exception: ', err.toString());
       if (err.stack) {
           console.error(err.stack);
       }
   });

   // create the express application
   const app = express();
   // server the static content, i.e. index.html
   app.use(express.static(__dirname));
   // start the server
   const server = app.listen(3000);
   // create the web socket
   const wss = new ws.Server({
       noServer: true,
       perMessageDeflate: false
   });
   server.on('upgrade', (request: http.IncomingMessage, socket: net.Socket, head: Buffer) => {
       const pathname = request.url ? url.parse(request.url).pathname : undefined;
       if (pathname === '/sampleServer') {
           wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, webSocket => {
               const socket: rpc.IWebSocket = {
                   send: content => webSocket.send(content, error => {
                       if (error) {
                           throw error;
                       }
                   }),
                   onMessage: cb => webSocket.on('message', cb),
                   onError: cb => webSocket.on('error', cb),
                   onClose: cb => webSocket.on('close', cb),
                   dispose: () => webSocket.close()
               };
               // launch the server when the web socket is opened
               if (webSocket.readyState === webSocket.OPEN) {
                   launch(socket);
               } else {
                   webSocket.on('open', () => launch(socket));
               }
           });
       }
   })
   ```
4. The Monaco client websocket is depliyed on port `4000`.

I run my `Eclipse JDT` server using the code:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Dlog.level=ALL -noverify -Xmx1G -jar ./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar -configuration ./config_linux -data /home/n --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -CLIENT_PORT=4000
```

I run my monaco client using the following command:

```
yarn run start
```

The problem is that both (Eclipse JDT and Monaco client along with the websocket) are up and active on their respective ports, but are not communicating.

How can I connect the Eclpse JDT to Monaco client's websocket?

Comment: @namanb009 Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below code in - `monaco-languageclient/example/src/json-server-launcher.ts`

```
        const serverConnection = server.createServerProcess('JSON', 'java', [
        '-Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1', 
        '-Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4',
        '-Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product',
        '-Dlog.level=ALL',
        '-noverify',
        '-Xmx1G',
        '-jar',
        '/home/pawansingh/projects/eclipse.jdt.ls/org.eclipse.jdt.ls.product/target/repository/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar',
        '-configuration',
        '/home/pawansingh/projects/eclipse.jdt.ls/org.eclipse.jdt.ls.product/target/repository/config_linux',
        '-data',
        '/home/pawansingh/projects/monaco-languageclient/example/src/java',        
        '--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM',
        '--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '-DCLIENT_PORT=4000'
    ]);
```

***NOTE: -- change the folder names as per your project setup.***